# Se puede cambiar el pathname de la ruta sin recargar la página?

Tags: router, next.js

Next.js te permite hacer uso del `{shallow: true}` para modificar parametros de la url sin recargar la página.

Yo estoy buscando hacer algo como lo siguiente:

Me encuentro en la página

`http://localhost/soyElPathnameActual`

Quisiera que la url del navegador ahora cambie a

`http://localhost/soyUnPathnameNuevo`

**Y que al cambiar el pathname no se recargue la página.**

Con `router.push` o `router.replace`, haciendo uso de `shallow`, la página se recarga de todos modos y tiene sentido porque según la documentación esto sirve para cambios dentro de la misma pagina.

Answer (score 0):

Lo resolvi de esta manera

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (window !== "undefined") {
      window.history.pushState(null, "", "/soyUnPathnameNuevo");
    }
  }, []);
```